# Private Ethereum blockchain not working for static ip

Tags: ethereum, blockchain, metamask

i have deployed an private ethereum network.in metamask while adding new its working for on Localhost:8545 or http:127.0.0.1:8545 .but when i add it with 192.168.0.5{my local address} it show  error "Could not fetch chain ID. Is your RPC URL correct?".

i have tried it with mac and ubuntu on same machine and network.

Comment: This question lacks details how you have deployed private ethereum network (config files, command lines) so it is unanswerable. My guess is that you used GoEthereum and forget to bind the correct IP address for JSON-RPC.

Comment: @Mikko Ohtamaa thanks , yes i am using go ethereum , geth i working on local system its working fine on localhost , but its not working http://192.168.1.51/ that is my local ip it show error "Could not fetch chain ID. Is your RPC URL correct?"